# “Deep-link” to a particular view state of an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, restore, deep-linking

Let's say that you have a navigation view controller hierarchy like this:

```
A => B => C
```

The user spends most of their time in `B`, hopping over to `C` only when it's their turn to supply input.

If their turn comes up while the app is backgrounded, they get a local notification. Tapping on that local notification *should* take them straight to `C`.

In my current implementation, when the user taps on the local notification, the `AppDelegate` receives it via `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`. It then finds `B` and instructs it to segue to `C`.

If the app has been unloaded, however, this won't work. When the user eventually acts upon the local notification, the app receives it through `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, meaning that it has to start all the way back at `A`.

Since this problem generalizes to one about “deep linking” to a particular state of an app, my question is:

**What's your best strategy for “deep linking” to `A => B => C` in response to a local notification having been acted upon, given that the current state of the app could be anything?**